# void swap(int *a, int *b) ; Why does swap(a,b) work?

Tags: c++

The prototype of my `swap` function is `void swap(int *a, int *b)`; why is it invoked when I call `swap(a, b)` where `a` and `b` are integers?

#### Full program

```
#include <iostream>
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int a = 9, b = 8;
    cout << "before swap:" << endl;
    cout << a << '\t' << b << endl;
    swap(a, b);
    cout << "after swap:" << endl;
    cout << a << '\t' << b << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

#### Observed behavior

> ```
> before swap:
> 9    8
> after swap:
> 8    9
> ```

I know it should have been `swap(&a,&b)` to call the function `swap`. Why does it work nonetheless?

Comment: You've likely included `std::swap` via `#include <iostream>`. Your swap doesn't look like it's ever used. Another example of `using namespace std;` leading to subtle errors.

Comment: Because you have `using namespace std`. You have `std::swap`, not your swap. Bad practice to use this command.

Comment: This is [why `using namespace std` is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5470596).

Comment: I think there are lots of similar questions on SO with exactly the same `swap`.

Comment: It didn’t use your swap function

Comment: @YSC I have heard this in the univercity, but without examples, and I'm not working with C, and now I actually know why it is a bad practice. I have upvoted the question for your comment :)

Comment: This is not a bad question per se. You provided us with a [mcve], explained the observed behavior and why it surprises you. This is just a classic error we've seen many times. Don't be sorry.

Comment: I am sorry ！ I have got it .Thank you !

Comment: Most of the times, when the users ask or search for something like this, they don't have any idea of what "using namespace std" means. Actually, the way this question is, it can be more useful than the one linked as a dupe.